# How to set fastcgi_params_hash_max_size?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

On my Ubuntu server running Nginx + FastCGI (via [Webinoly](https://webinoly.com/en/)), nginx -t throws the following warning:

```
    nginx: [warn] could not build optimal fastcgi_params_hash, 
you should increase either fastcgi_params_hash_max_size: 512 or 
fastcgi_params_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring fastcgi_params_hash_bucket_size
```

At first I thought that I had to change server_names_hash_max_size, but it was already set to 2048 and was unrelated. To make sure, I tried lowering its value to 8, at which nginx -t threw a warning that I should increase it. After restoring it, I got back the initial warning about fastcgi_params_hash_max_size.

I also tried setting fastcgi_params_hash_max_size on my nginx.conf file, but then I got an error that fastcgi_params_hash_max_size is an unknown directive.

So, I guess my question is, how can I change the fastcgi_params_hash_max_size?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed no `fastcgi_params_hash_max_size` and `fastcgi_params_hash_bucket_size` directives. This error message is "automatic" in a way that it takes the hash name (in this case `fastcgi_params_hash`) then constructs suggested directive names by appending `_max_size` and `_bucket_size`.

The NGINX hashes in general are used to store array-like configuration data like `map`s or `fastcgi_params`s (your case), and there is separate [document](https://nginx.org/en/docs/hash.html) about them having to say:

> **Most** hashes have the corresponding directives that allow changing these parameters, for example, for the server names hash they are server_names_hash_max_size and server_names_hash_bucket_size.

So your hash does not have the "corresponding directives" and there is nothing you can do aside from:

- Investigate why you have too many `fastcgi_param` directives in your configuration? (or with too much lengthy values). It very likely that you have suboptimal configuration in regards with `fastcgi_params`s. Remember, those are passed to FastCGI (e.g. PHP-FPM), and if that data is too big, then you sure to experience performance issues simply because of much data going through between NGINX-PHP-FPM.
- File a bug issue with NGINX about adding these directives